# Processing JSON response in Azure Function from query to Azure IOT Hub

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I'm new to C# and having trouble processing queries into the desired format. If i run the code this way the response is:

```
["{\r\n  \"Plant\": \"1195118\"\r\n}","{\r\n  \"Plant\": \"1195157\"\r\n}"]
```

Which isn't the desired result. The actual desired output is a JSON of the following format:

```
{
"plant":["123235", "1195157"]
}
```

The code i'm using is below. I have tried  several options but i'm struggling with the C# handling of JSON.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
string queryString = "SELECT properties.reported.Plant_Number FROM devices WHERE properties.reported.Plant_Number != null";
IQuery query = registryManager.CreateQuery(queryString);
var json = (await query.GetNextAsJsonAsync());
return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(json);
```

Comment: Can you try to replace the last line with this: `return Content(json, "application/json");`

Comment: I don't see any issues with the first JSON. can you please explain a little bit on what kind of error you are receiving

Comment: I am having trouble changing the format of the JSON response from format of the first example to the second example. A common error response is: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you want is a single object, and the JSON you are getting is an array with one entry that is a string. In short: you need to parse the JSON.

```
var json = (await query.GetNextAsJsonAsync()); 
return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(json);
```

The first line returns an enumerable of strings, the second line returns it to the caller. So that's why the result you are getting is an array with strings.

If you want it to returns JSON instead, you will need to parse the string. To do that, you can use the JsonConvert class in the NewtonSoft.Json library (comes with your Function by default). You can learn about that [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm).

Edit after author's comment:

```
var jsonStrings = await query.GetNextAsJsonAsync();
var deviceProperties = jsonStrings.Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceProperty>);
return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(deviceProperties);

public class DeviceProperty
{
    public string Plant { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If i implement:

    var next = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlantList>(json);

I get the following error:

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Comment: I edited my answer to include a more complete code sample. DeserializeObject expects a string and you feed it an enumerable of strings. Instead, the Select method will iterate through all of the strings and deserialize them.